# Stored procedure's parameter was not supplied in aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, gridview

I want to display data in a gridview using a SQL Server stored procedure. The interface should include two textboxes for two parameters, one button, and a gridview. The data will display after all parameters are filled out and the button is clicked. But I got an error saying

> 'Procedure or function 'uspGetBillOfMaterials' expects parameter '@StartProductID', which was not supplied.'

**Edit 1**: I found out that I called parameter `StartProducID` instead of `StartProductID`. Thank you guys for helping me with this. I fixed the problem.

Now I get a new error:

> Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

Hope you can help me figure out where is my problem and the way to fix it.

Thanks.

**Edit 2**: I figured out my problems and posted the answer below. Basically, I just deleted the last two rows in my code-behind and it worked.

Here is my code in ASP.NET:

```
Please enter StartedProduct <asp:TextBox ID="StartProductID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
Please enter Date <asp:TextBox ID="CheckDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search BOM" />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="TestProc" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductAssemblyID" HeaderText="ProductAssemblyID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductAssemblyID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ComponentID" HeaderText="ComponentID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ComponentID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ComponentDesc" HeaderText="ComponentDesc" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ComponentDesc" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalQuantity" HeaderText="TotalQuantity" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalQuantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StandardCost" HeaderText="StandardCost" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="StandardCost" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ListPrice" HeaderText="ListPrice" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ListPrice" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BOMLevel" HeaderText="BOMLevel" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="BOMLevel" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RecursionLevel" HeaderText="RecursionLevel" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RecursionLevel" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="TestProc" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorks2014ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="uspGetBillOfMaterials" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="StartProductID" Name="StartProductID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckDate" Name="CheckDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my code-behind:

```
Public Class TestStoredProcedure

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim command As New SqlCommand()
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim sql As String = Nothing
    Dim connetionString As String = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2014;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    connection.Open()
    command.Connection = connection
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.CommandText = "uspGetBillOfMaterials"
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartProductID", StartProductID.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckDate", CheckDate.Text)
    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    adapter.Fill(ds)
    connection.Close()
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "expects parameter '@StartProductID'" - look at the name you provided.

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartProducID", StartProductID.Text) is that a type that should say StartProductID ?

Comment: Oh thank you!!! What a stupid mistake...

Comment: @TnTinMn Thank you! I fixed the problem and now it says "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition." Could you help me with this?

Comment: @Hursey Thank you for pointing out. I fixed this problem. Now I have a new error is "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1". Could you please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problems:

The first error was because of a wrong parameter's name. It should be "StartProductID" instead of "StartProducID".

The second error was because I defined the gridview in both C# code and Vb code. I deleted the last two rows in my code-behind and it worked. Here is the **[link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/255064/Both-DataSource-and-DataSourceID-are-defined-on-Gr)** that helped me solve my issue.

Thank you all.

Comment: Why not just flat out state that you had both the data source defined in the grid, and if you use code you have to remove that setting. The error message was 100% clear. If you use code then delete the datasource on the page, and go and remove the setting in the datagrid propety sheet. This had ZERO to do with some stuff about C# and vb.net code. And of course you can't define a page to have both vb and c# code.

Comment: Glad that you've got the solution. Maybe you can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thank you for your comment. I'm a newbie with ASP.net and both C# and VB. That's why I couldn't interpret the error message. Anyways, thank you for all the helps, I learnt my lesson.